# What is the AttributeContext in Milo OpcUA?

Tags: server, opc-ua, milo, node-opcua

I would like to update the data in server, I could not find a way to update my current Variable Nodes..
I can see in the write/read example that there is an AttributeContext passed into the function..
1. Do I need that to update my Variable Nodes?
2. If I do, How do I get that AttributeContext?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to just call `VariableNode#setValue` on your `VariableNode`s and then read that attribute back when you implement `AttributeManager#read` in your `Namespace`. See the `ExampleNamespace` for what that might look like.

There's any number of other approaches, it's all up to you. Implementing the `Namespace` is where the SDK stops doing the work and it's your turn to do programming.